# Use nodemailer to send AMP email

Tags: node.js, c#-4.0, nodemailer, mailkit, amp-email

I recently came to know about AMP email and found it interesting and tried an example in nodejs using nodemailer package.

This package already contains an option 'amp' to send AMP specific emails, however I am unable to make it work.

The AMP version of email is really plain and it doesnt contain any xhr requests. 
Below is my code which sends an email to a specific email address.

```
  let transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: "validuser@gsuiteBusinessdomain.com",
      pass: "validpassword"
  },
  });

  let mailOptions = {
    from: 'sender@gsuiteBusinessdomain.com', // sender address
    to: "enduser@gsuiteBusinessdomain.com", // list of receivers
    subject: "test subject", // Subject line
    text: " basic text body example ", // plain text body
    html: '<b>basic html body example</b>', // html body
    amp: `<!--
        Below is the mininum valid AMP4EMAIL document. Just type away
        here and the AMP Validator will re-check your document on the fly.
   -->
   <!doctype html>
   <html ⚡4email>
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
     <style amp4email-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden}</style>
   </head>
   <body>
     Hello, AMP4EMAIL world.
   </body>
   </html>`
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
  });
```

Also, I tried using "MailKit" package in C# but was not sure how to set an AMP version here. I added my AMP version under message.body section
 of MimeMessage class.

```
 message.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.RichText)
            {
                Text = @"<!-- ........
```

I am sure there is something really small that I am missing but unable to figure it out.
Could someone take a look and guide me whats going wrong with above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMP isn't RichText, it's HTML with a special Content-Type that is meant to be part of a `multipart/alternative`.

I would recommend reading https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-email-format

To send AMP in MimeKit/MailKit, you would do something like this:

```
var alternative = new MultipartAlternative ();
alternative.Add (new TextPart ("plain") {
    Text = "This is the plain-text message body."
});

// Note: Some email clients[1] will only render the last MIME part, so we
// recommend placing the text/x-amp-html MIME part before the text/html
// MIME part.
alternative.Add (new TextPart ("x-amp-html") {
    Text = @"<!--
    Below is the minimum valid AMP4EMAIL document. Just type away
    here and the AMP Validator will re-check your document on the fly.
-->
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡4email>
<head>
  <meta charset=""utf-8"">
  <script async src=""https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js""></script>
  <style amp4email-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden}</style>
</head>
<body>
  Hello, AMP4EMAIL world.
</body>
</html>"
});

alternative.Add (new TextPart ("html") {
    Text = "This is the <b>html</b> message body."
});

message.Body = alternative;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jstedfast. I should have mentioned it before. I used even HTML format and that didnt give me a AMP page rather just a HTML page

Comment: I think you are confused (or maybe I am?) about what, exactly, AMP email is. Based on the text you are setting the message body to, that is HTML. So when you tell me "yea, but it shows up as HTML" I think "well, duh, because it *is*". Why are you expecting something different?

Comment: Never mind, I see the problem, you need a special mime-type. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I was looking for. thanks for guiding me to right path